# How to re-crawl documents that have an error status

Tags: google-search-appliance

We had an issue yesterday that prevented gsa crawler from loging in to our website to crawl. Because of this many of the URLs are indexed as the login page. I see a lot of results on the search page titled "Please log in" (title of the login page). Also when I check Index Diagnostics the crawl status for these URLs are "`Retrying URL: Connection reset by peer during fetch.`".

Now the login problem is resolved and once a page is re-crawled the crawl status goes to successful and it is picking up the page content and the search results show up with the proper title.. But since I cannot control what is being crawled there are pages that still haven't been re-crawled and still have the problem.

There is not a uniform URL that I can force a re-crawl. Hence my question:
Is there a way to force a re-crawl based on the crawl status ("`Retrying URL: Connection reset by peer during fetch.`")? If that is to specific how about a re-crawl based on crawl status type (`Errors/Successful/Excluded`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Export all the error url as csv file using "Index> Diagnostics >
   Index Diagnostics"
2. Open CSV and apply filter on crawl status colum and get urls having
       the error you are looking for.
3. Copy those urls and goto "Content Sources > Web Crawl > Freshness
       Tuning>Recrawl these URL Patterns" and paste and click on Recrawl

That's it. You are done!

PS: If error urls are more (>10000,If I am not wrong), you may not be able to get all of them in a single csv file. In that case you can do in batches.

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: Thanks. I thought about the export but didn't know that there is a place to copy paste these URLs for re-crawl. Do you know whether there is a limit on how many URLs to submit at once on the Freshness Tuning > Recrawl URL Patterns form?

Comment: Exporting via Index Diagnostics does have a cap of 10k URLs if you use the Export All Pages to a File button.
For exporting you're better to use the dedicated Export URLs function: Index > Diagnostics > Export URLs which doesn't have the 10k limit. (But may result in a file too large to open in Excel if you don't do any filtering).

I don't know of any limit to the number of URLs you can paste in to that field in Freshness Tuning but as it's posting string data to the GSA don't go too crazy and do them in batches to make sure you don't miss any.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any idea about limit on how many urls to submit on freshness tuning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to submit a batch of URLs for recrawling:
https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit/blob/master/interactive-feed-client.html

I have tested in batches of 80K at once.